# MS SQL update table with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Been reading this site for answers for quite a while and now asking my first question!

I'm using SQL Server

I have two tables, **ABC** and **ABC_Temp**.

The contents are inserted into the **ABC_Temp** first before making its way to ABC.
Table **ABC** and **ABC_Temp** have the same columns, except that **ABC_Temp** has an extra column called LastUpdatedDate, which contains the date of the last update. Because **ABC_Temp** can have more than 1 of the same record, it has a composite key of the item number and the last updated date.

The columns are: ItemNo | Price | Qty and **ABC_Temp** has an extra column: LastUpdatedDate

I want to create a statement that follows the following conditions:

1. Check if each of the attributes of **ABC** differ from the value of **ABC_Temp** for records with the same key, if so then do the update (Even if only one attribute is different, all other attributes can be updated as well)
2. Only update those that need changes, if the record is the same, then it would not update.
3. Since an item can have more than one record in **ABC_Temp** I only want the latest updated one to be updated to **ABC**

I am currently using 2005 (I think, not at work at the moment).

This will be in a stored procedure and is called inside the VBscript scheduled task. So I believe it is a once time thing. Also I'm not trying to sync the two tables, as the contents of ABC_Temp would only contain new records bulk inserted from a text file through BCP. For the sake of context, this will be used with in conjunction with an insert stored proc that checks if records exist.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Please, describe the usage scenario - is this one time job, where you want to sync 2 tables only once, or you plan to do it on a schedule. Or you want to do it dynamically - whenever a new record is pushed to ABC_Temp, you need to update ABC.

Comment: This will be in a stored procedure and is called inside the VBscript scheduled task. So I believe it is a once time thing. Also I'm not trying to sync the two tables, as the contents of ABC_Temp would only contain new records bulk inserted from a text file through BCP.

For the sake of context, this will be used with in conjunction with an insert stored proc that checks if records exist

Comment: update the question and add a comment pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    ABC
SET
    price = T1.price,
    qty = T1.qty
FROM
    ABC
INNER JOIN ABC_Temp T1 ON
    T1.item_no = ABC.item_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC_Temp T2 ON
    T2.item_no = T1.item_no AND
    T2.last_updated_date > T1.last_updated_date
WHERE
    T2.item_no IS NULL AND
    (
        T1.price <> ABC.price OR
        T1.qty <> ABC.qty
    )
```

If NULL values are possible in the `price` or `qty` columns then you will need to account for that. In this case I would probably change the inequality statements to look like this:

```
COALESCE(T1.price, -1) <> COALESCE(ABC.price, -1)
```

This assumes that -1 is not a valid value in the data, so you don't have to worry about it actually appearing there.

Also, is ABC_Temp really a temporary table that's just loaded long enough to get the values into ABC? If not then you are storing duplicate data in multiple places, which is a bad idea. The first problem is that now you need these kinds of update scenarios. There are other issues that you might run into, such as inconsistencies in the data, etc.

Comment: Yes, the ABC_Temp is really a temp. All records in ABC_Temp is deleted at the start of the VBScript before the bcp insert into the table. So ABC_Temp acts as a filter of the records before it is put in the permanent table ABC. I will try this approach as well tomorrow, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me!
But what I don't really get is why T2.item_no IS NULL?

Comment: The only way that T2.item_no can be NULL (assuming it's a NOT NULL column) is if the LEFT OUTER JOIN failed to find a matching row. So, what the query says is, only give me those rows where you can't find a T2 that's after the T1 row... or, T1 is the latest possible row. It's basically an alternative way of doing a NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cross apply` to seek the last row in `ABC_Temp` with the same key.  Use a `where` clause to filter out rows with no differences:

```
update  abc
set     col1 = latest.col1
,       col2 = latest.col2
,       col3 = latest.col3
from    ABC abc
cross apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    ABC_Temp tmp
        where   abc.key = tmp.key
        order by
                tmp.LastUpdatedDate desc
        ) latest
where   abc.col1 <> latest.col1
        or (abc.col2 <> latest.col2
            or (abc.col1 is null and latest.col2 is not null)
            or (abc.col1 is not null and latest.col2 is null))
        or abc.col3 <> latest.col3
```

In the example, only `col2` is nullable.  Since `null <> 1` is not true, you have to check differences involving null using the `is null` syntax.

Comment: Wont checking for `latest.col2 is null` result in some rows being set to `null` if they already have values?